# How to free-up RAM after a multiprocessing task in python on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, memory-management, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing in python on jupyter notebook. I am able to parallelize the code using pool of workers. I am facing the problem of memory deallocation.

```
import multiprocessing

def forSources(n):
   temp_pairings = []
   temp_pairings += dfs_edges2(digraph, flights[n[0]], n[1])
   print(multiprocessing.current_process().name, len(temp_pairings))
   return (temp_pairings)

for depth in range(0, 2):
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   result = pool.map(forSources, [[i, depth] for i in range(0, 3000)])
   for pairings in result:
      final_result += pairings
   if len(final_result) > 5000:
      break
   pool.terminate()
   pool.join()
```

After extracting the `final_result`, I want to free the RAM as soon as the processes gets terminated.

For example: this run takes about 3.5 GB of the RAM and after the run is completed, the system monitor is still showing the extra 3.5 GB. I have tried deleting all the variables formed, even closing the jupyter notebook is not solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try storing the process id of all the spawned processes and after completion kill all the process.